# SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM fails on MySQL when used for views referencing other views

Tags: mysql, database-administration

**All of this is tested with `root` user on MySQL 8.0.18 with full privileges**

Running `SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM first_view;` works as expected when `first_view` references other tables. However, running the same for another view (`second_view`) which references `first_view` (or any other view), fails with the following error:

```
View 'second_view' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them. (Error #1356)
```

This is not due to "corrupt" views as I have dropped and recreated both views and they both return results without any issues.

Can anyone help shed some light on this please?

*Update 1*: It doesn't seem to matter what `first_view` or `second_view` views are. The issue happens regardless.

*Update 2*: This only happens on the Google CloudSQL hosted database, which makes me think it could be caused by a DB flag.

Comment: Not reproduced on 8.0.27 - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=911356e817e754f1bfb60087b59ad593 Maybe this is version issue?

Comment: please check the definition of second_view

Comment: @Manik given that out of many views, the only ones failing this are the ones with a reference to another view, what should I be checking for?